# Data used in Reinhart & Rogoff's "Growth in a Time of Debt"

Tags: data-request, economics

Is the data used in the infamous ["Growth in a Time of Debt"](http://www.nber.org/papers/w15639) paper available somewhere? (Either the uncorrected or the corrected version.)

More info about the paper: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Growth_in_a_Time_of_Debt

Comment: You could mail the authors. Their email address is in the paper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RR never posted their working spreadsheet, however some of the supporting data can be found on their website. That being said, the exact data used in their spreadsheet was posted with the Herndon, Ash, Pollin replication working paper here: http://www.peri.umass.edu/236/hash/31e2ff374b6377b2ddec04deaa6388b1/publication/566/

The final version of the HAP paper can be found here: http://cje.oxfordjournals.org/content/early/2013/12/17/cje.bet075